# Synchronize Excel with SharePoint List programatically using Angular JS

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, synchronization

I am working with requirement where I have to develop an Excel Task pane add-in to which will synchronize the data of SharePoint Online list and Excel sheet using Angular JS.

Authentication part is solved, the only remaining part is updating excel data using AJ. So what I want to know, is there any sample code available in AJ using which I can write data to the Excel cell at any row and any column?

I would like to add that I don't need any software tool or out of the box facility available in SharePoint or in Excel. I need to achieve it purely by code.